# Make IDEA detect unresolved attributes in a decorated class

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pycharm, decorator, jetbrains-ide

I've got a decorator which returns its argument unchanged, that is `Deco(cls) == cls`. IDEA (most recent version) fails to report unresolved attributes on a decorated class.

I guess I have to provide some clever type hinting for `Deco`. How would that look exactly?

```
class A:
    def foo(self):
        print(self)


A().foo()
A().no_such_thing()  # red line, correct


class Deco:
    def __call__(self, cls):
        return cls


@Deco()
class B:
    def foo(self):
        print(self)


B().foo()
B().no_such_thing()  # no red line, WRONG
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-30190, feel free to vote for it and leave comments.

Comment: will do, thanks!